# My form will not submit on the website. It just shows blank page at mail.php

Tags: php, linux, web, nginx, phpmailer

What am I doing wrong. There is a html form that takes three inputs Name, Notes, and Phone. The action on the form is mail.php and method is POST.

Here is the code in mail.php. On success I want it to return to homepage.

```
 <?php
// multiple recipients
//$to  = 'waleed.dogar@gmail.com' . ', '; // note the comma

error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
require_once('/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('/phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->Subject    =  'Form Submission on Website';
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$notes = $_REQUEST['notes'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;

$body = "You have received a new message from $name.\n". "Here is the phone number:\n $phone". "Here are the additional notes: \n $notes";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 80;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "alex@acemobiledetailing.ca"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('example@example.ca', 'Alex Website');

$mail->AddReplyTo("example@example.ca","Alex ");                            

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "example@gmail.com";

$mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
$mail-> Send();

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
  GOTO(http://example.com/thankyou.php);
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you look inside php error log? `GOTO(http://example.com/thankyou.php);` won't work, I think you should use `header("Location: http://example.com/thankyou.php")`.

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of script, or check your virtual host configuration for entries like `ErrorLog`. If you using apache and linux they're probably inside `/var/log/apache`

Comment: i checked my error log there is a error 500 5 on mail.php

Comment: Your include path is wrong for phpMailer. PHP does not see those files. Set correct path for them. Read here: http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: So i fixed the include path and it is still showing me a blank page and nothing happens. What is error 500 supposed to mean? i am running on nginx on linux server

Comment: okay now it shows error 200 32 what is that

Comment: Are you really looking at error log or maybe access log? Paste full error message.

Comment: i am looking at access log. where can i see the error log

Comment: Probably in same directory access log is in.

Comment: ipaddress - - [13/May/2014:21:26:33 +0000] "POST /mail.php HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "websitename" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1984.1 Safari/537.36"

Comment: It's acces log not error log...